# Assertion failure while deleting entity from core data model

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an application using Microsoft Azure. I am facing this problem but unable to understand the reason behind it. When user clicks on "logout" button I want to clear all local data storage if available.Currently I am having 7 entities in core data model which I have to clear using below code:

```
- (void) deleteAllObjects: (NSString *) entityDescription  {
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
        [context deleteObject:managedObject];
        NSLog(@"%@ object deleted",entityDescription);
    }
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",entityDescription,error);
    }
}
```

and I am calling this method in below manner:

```
NSArray *entityNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Medicine", @"Allergy",@"MedicalInfo", @"Note", @"Profile", @"TodoItem", @"Vital", nil];
for (NSString *entity in entityNames) {
        [self deleteAllObjects:entity];
}
```

and I am getting below error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1582  2015-04-27 16:21:00.334 ARKAA-IOS[18570:4080663] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'  *** First throw call stack:
(0x21a8fc1f 0x2f23ac8b 0x21a8faf5 0x2275fd7f 0x251197ef 0x8b98b 0x65a9db 0x65a9c7 0x65e3ed 0x21a559d1 0x21a540d1 0x219a2211 0x219a2023 0x28d9b0a9 0x24fae1d1 0x142501 0x2f7baaaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It looks like you have a fetchedResults object linked to a tableview but your delegate method isn't handling the deletes correctly.  The message says that your `numberOfRowsInSection` reported 0 but you didn't call `deleteRowsAtIndex`

Comment: @Paulw11, you are absolutely right

Comment: @Arti you need to delete the row as well after updating the modal.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I agree that my delegate is not responding properly. Actually I need you guys help in that part too. Please see the update.